# ArgumentError in Rails::MailersController#preview (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, railstutorial.org

I am working on Chapter 10 of the Rails Tutorial. I've skipped the account activation and implemented the password reset mailer. Here is the code: of user_mailer_preview.rb

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  # Preview this email at
  # http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/password_reset
  def password_reset
    user = User.first
    user.reset_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.password_reset(user)
  end
end
```

Here is the code of the user mailer itself:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
  #
  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/password_reset` I am getting

[image: ArgumentError in Mailer]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling  `UserMailer.password_reset(user)`   and passing in the user

but your `password_reset` method does not take an argument. So either you will need to change your password_reset to take a user (and do something with it)

```
def password_reset(user)
   #do something with the user, such as send to their email address  
   @greeting = "Hi"
   mail to: user.email 
end
```

or adjust your call to be `UserMailer.password_reset`  without the user.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here because the method expected arguments but none were provided, you can fix this by changing the default preview to have some default data for the parameter you're providing to your mailer method.

There is a brilliant explanation with code [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUFgOiYP9yM#t=2m50s)